# jQuery $.get not returning data anymore

Tags: cakephp, jquery, jquery-post

I am using jQuery-1.4.2 with CakePHP and a few days ago I had this working fine but now it isn't.  I don't remember changing anything.  I am taking the URL generated from the javascript and putting that directly into the browser and I am able to see the results in my browser however javascript is just getting a return value of null.  Anyone have ides?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var url = "http://mysite.com/vote/";

        $.get(url + "view/" + $(".votediv").attr("id")  +".json" ,
                function(data,textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                    console.log(data);
                    console.log(textStatus);
                    console.log(XMLHttpRequest);
                    if(data.Votes.votecast != undefined) {

                        $(".vote."+data.Votes.votecast).addClass("current");
                    }
                },"json");
        $('.vote').click(function () {
            if ($(this).hasClass("current")) {
                alert("You have already voted for this option!");
            } else {

                var error = false;

                if ($(this).hasClass("up")) {

                    $.post(url + "edit/" + $(".votediv").attr("id")  +".json", {'vote': 'up'},
                        function(data) {
                            console.log(data);
                        }, "json");
                    //alert("Voted Up!");
                }
                else if($(this).hasClass("down")) {
                    $.post(url + "edit/" + $(".votediv").attr("id")  +".json", {'vote': 'down'},
                        function(data) {
                            console.log(data);
                        }, "json");
                    //alert("Voted Down!");
                }
                //removes all the votes
                $(this).parent().children().removeClass("current");

                if(!error) {
                    $(this).addClass("current");
                } else {
                    alert("There was an error");
                }
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Output from debug console in browser is

```
null
success

XMLHttpRequest
    abort: function () {x&&h.call(x);
    onabort: null
    onerror: null
    onload: null
    onloadstart: null
    onprogress: null
    onreadystatechange: function () {}
    readyState: 4
    responseText: ""
    responseXML: null
    status: 0
    statusText: ""
    upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload
    withCredentials: false
    __proto__: XMLHttpRequestPrototype

TypeError: Result of expression 'data' [null] is not an object.
Failed to load resource: cancelled
```

The output my php script does is

```
{"Votes":{"votecast":"up","sumvotes":"1","totalvotes":"1"}}
```

I'm wondering why I keep getting null data.  Any ideas?  I am not doing a cross domain query.  I am only querying a script on my domain.

EDIT:

I have changed the JSON output to display as `{"Votes":{"votecast":"up","sumvotes":"1","totalvotes":"1"}}` and jsonlint.com says it is valid JSON however it still does not work and jQuery says the result is null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see that you are specifying the URL in the start of your script:

```
var url = "http://mysite.com/vote/";
```

Could it be that your are violating the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)? Ie. that you can only do ajax calls to the originating server.

That would give you the symptoms you describe: a blank response, but the URL works when tried manually through the browser.

Comment: As mentioned in my question I have stated that I am querying a script on my server and not doing any cross domain query.

Comment: it looks like you are right.  It turns out if I use www in my browser since I don't have www specified in my jQuery url it causes that issue.  Why would www violate the same origin policy?  Is there a jQuery function to get the browsers base url so I can use that?

Comment: Same origin triggers on different subdomains as well. You can use relative URLs, just go to "/vote/".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it's not returning data, but you might want to make sure the url $.get is going to is the one you think it is. You could use `alert(url + "view/" + $(".votediv").attr("id")  +".json");` for example - of course you can also see that in Firebug.

I believe `$.get` can sometimes return a status of 'success' even if it's not actually loading a url.

Comment: I have stated in my above post that I have already confirmed the url is correct by outputting the url and testing it manually.